# Cannot Find Symbol compiler message

Tags: java

Hello all I'm a java newbie and I'm getting a compiler error message:

```
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor File(java.lang.StringBuffer)
location: class java.io.File
   static File Rqst_File = new File(RqstFile_DSN) ;
                           ^
```

In my java program I have coded:

```
   static StringBuffer RqstFile_DSN = new StringBuffer() ;
   static StringBuffer RespFile_DSN = new StringBuffer() ;

   static File Rqst_File = new File(RqstFile_DSN) ;
```

Any ideas as to why the compiler can't find the RqstFile_DSN "symbol" ? 
I'm assuming that the "symbol"  is the variable I've defined RqstFile_DSN

Thanks

Comment: Try `new File(RqstFile_DSN.toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is slightly misleading. The problem is that `new File` cannot take a `StringBuilder` object as a parameter. This ought to work:

```
static File Rqst_File = new File(RqstFile_DSN.toString()) ;
```

Comment: except that RqstFile_DSN is an empty StringBuilder

Comment: Hmmmm ... well my issue is this: while the file name is pre-determined (i.e. "RqstFile.txt") the path isn't, I won't know the path name until "runtime" when it's passed via the args[] list. I therefore have to : RqstFile_DSN.append = Path_name ;

Answer (score 1):

The error message is,

> cannot find symbol : constructor File(java.lang.StringBuffer)

There is no File constructor that takes a StringBuffer, you need to pass it a String instead.

Try something like,

```
static final String rqstFile_DSN = "theFileName";
static final File rqstFile = new File(rqstFile_DSN) ;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your insight and suggestions.